# Unable to change Hint Text Appearance Color for TextInputLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

What needs to be Achieved ?

I am trying to change the hint text color of the TextInputLayout programatically when the TextInputLayout losses its focus using the attribute :

**InputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.SetFocusTheme)**

But when the focus is lost, from the inputlayout to some other widget the theme doesn't work.It seems like it picks the theme attributes from the activity from that point onward ,till it again gains focus.

Following are the styles defined for SetHasFocusTheme

```
 <style name="CustomTextAppearanceLostFocus"   
parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textColor">#23FFAB</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#23FFAB</item>    
    </style>
```

I have searched alot for the same,but did not came across a full proof solution for the same,because my understanding is with this type of limited control,where we cannot change the text hint color of the TextInputLayout Widget when it has focus or when it looses focus cripples us since we  do not have a full control over the widget style which is really bad. I hope someone may have a better understanding on this and guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Dear first make a new layout

row_inputlayout_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput"

 />
```

In your code add this dynamically

```
TextInputLayout  input = new TextInputLayout(this);
  input = (TextInputLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_inputlayout_item, null);
```

set this style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="TextLabelInput" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_red</item>

</style>
```

You can add the theme in your style.xml set this in your project Androidmainfest.xml on your Desire activity

and also the whole answer used satisfied what you want

```
 <style name="YourTheme.Base"   parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#23FFAB</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#23FFAB</item>

// if you want customize use it
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryTransparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Try this.. I am sure It is help you 100%...

Comment: Thanks Arjun,but the given solution doesn't solve the actual question.I do not want to add a new TextInputLayout dynamically but i want to change the text hint color of the TextInputLayout  dynamicallyat runtime which is already defined in xml with different style as per the use case.

Comment: it's add at run time.. see in answer.. I am adding layout at run time.. there is no other option to set color to TextInputLayout

Comment: We can add it,if u look at the methods of the TextInputLayout,there is a one "setTextAppearance(int resID)" through which we can pass the style guide reference

Comment: well arjun,it would just make a difference to the text size not color and even if u specify color it doesnt help :(

Comment: to change the hint color you can add this   label.setHintTextAppearance(Color.BLUE);

Comment: Yes,it does not change the label color,thats the main issue,according to documentation it should but it is not.

Comment: I have One solution also for this... can I share it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayout;
EditText editText = inputLayout.getEditText();
final OnFocusChangeListener existing = editText.getOnFocusChangeListener();

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
        existing.onFocusChange(view, focused);
        edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Anders,thanks for the reply,i tried your solution but i am getting null pointer exception for "existing" in existing.onFocusChange(view,focused)

Comment: remove that line and try

Comment: then do need to do some debugging